# Scrapy: Unable to access class despite of it's there

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape [this](http://www.rebeccaminkoff.com/stacey-sneaker-r17-light-blue) page, I am trying to fetch Color Name, *LT. BLUE*. From Chrome I see HTML:

```
<div id="desc-options"><div class="option"><span class="label">Color:</span> LT. BLUE</div><div class="option"><span class="label">Size:</span> 6.5</div></div>
```

I tried `response.css("#desc-options")` to access everything inside but returns `[]`. Even `BeautifulSoup` is failing.

Answer (score 2):

The element you're looking for is dynamically created via JavaScript. You cannot parse it from the plain HTML.

The good news is: the data you're looking for is probably still in the page. Check out the `<script>` tag defining the `spConfig` variable. Looks like there's some JSON there you can parse ...